# Combine data with SQL Server function with multiple output values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following case:

Table data_table:

```
ID  data
1   a;b;c
2   d;e;f
3   j


function datasplit:
dbo.[datasplit]('a;b;c', ';')
```

which will result in result table:

```
items 
a
b
c
```

I want to generate an output that will consist of the splitted data

```
ID  splitted_data
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   d
2   e
2   f
3   j
```

SQL query that Im trying to use:

```
select ID, (select * from dbo.[datasplit](data, ';')) as splitted_data 
FROM
data_table
```

Im getting and Error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Is there a way generating required result using a regular Query or there is a need for SP or other functions?

Comment: Whoever down-voted, please leave a comment when you do so.

Comment: Use the split function as a table and not as a column. `... FROM data_table CROSS APPLY dbo.datasplit ON data_table.columnToSplit = datasplit.InputColumn`

Comment: worked with cross apply. didnt require the ON... section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not execute the `TVF` in this way you can use `APPLY` operator:

```
select t.ID, t1.out_put_col_via_function as splitted_data 
from data_table t 
cross apply dbo.datasplit(t.data, ';') t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

@david, try with below solution and let me know is that works for you?

```
 SELECT A.[id],  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [id],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(DataVal, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  testtabl) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` to call a function that returns a set of values:

```
select t.ID, ds.col
from data_table t cross apply
     dbo.datasplit(data, ';') as ds(col);
```

Comment: Thanks - "as ds(col)" needed to define a different name. but all and all worked.